# ts-node/ts-jest won't allow me to import

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, ts-node

I'm encountering a syntax error when integrating mdast-util-from-markdown in my Jest tests for a TypeScript project. Looking for a solution that avoids using Babel.

My code runs fine using ts-node.

## Problem:

When I run my Jest tests, I receive the following error:

```
Details:

/Users/dudeman/ac/_utils/md-hierarchical-parser/node_modules/mdast-util-from-markdown/index.js:2
export {fromMarkdown} from './lib/index.js'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

> 1 | import { fromMarkdown } from "mdast-util-from-markdown";
```

## Current setup

#### Config:

`tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs", // Also tried "esnext"
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "test/**/*"
  ]
}
```

`jest.config.cjs`  (also tried `jest.config.js`)

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      useESM: true
    }
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1'
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts']
};
```

#### Runner

`npx jest`

`NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' npc jest`

## Tried

- Modifying my tsconfig.json to use different module settings (e.g., "esnext", "commonjs")
- Modifying jest.config.js to

  - handle ES module syntax,
  - `transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!unist-util-visit)'],`
- I also used babel (even though I'd prefer to not), and I still get the error :/

## Question:

How can I configure Jest and TypeScript to work with mdast-util-from-markdown without encountering the 'Unexpected token' error, and preferably without introducing Babel into my setup?

## Edit:

Seems to work with

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "esm": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib"]
}
```

`jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.{ts|tsx}?$': ['ts-jest', {
      useESM: true
    }],
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1'
  },
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts']
};
```

`package.json`

```json
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.13.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.13.1",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.10",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "jest": "29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
```

`jest --env=node --colors --coverage test`

Answer (score 1):

`react-markdown` comes with a ton of dependencies you have to ignore by jest config:

```js
// jest.config.js

const config = {
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(bail|ccount|character-entities|comma-separated-tokens|decode-named-*|escape-string-regexp|hast-util-*|is-plain-obj|markdown*|mdast-util-*|micromark*|property-information|react-markdown|remark-*|space-separated-*|trim-lines|trough|unified*|unist-util-*|vfile))',
  ],
};
```